# infinite type error reversing a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, infinite

I'm trying to implement the reverse of a list:

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [] = error "No end for empty lists!"
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs

myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse (x:xs) = myLast xs + myReverse xs
```

but I get this error:

```
/workspaces/hask_exercises/exercises/src/Lib.hs:42:32: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    * In the second argument of `(+)', namely `myReverse xs'
      In the expression: myLast xs + myReverse xs
      In an equation for `myReverse':
          myReverse (x : xs) = myLast xs + myReverse xs
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:42:14)
        x :: a (bound at src/Lib.hs:42:12)
        myReverse :: [a] -> [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:41:1)
   |
42 | myReverse (x:xs) = myLast xs + myReverse xs
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What does it mean that `cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]`? I get this error a lot and would like to understand what it means.

Comment: What do you think `+` does?

Comment: `++` is for concatenating lists.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica `myLast xs` is a number and `myReverse xs` is a list so it should add the number to the list

Comment: `+` is  for adding numbers to each other. `:` sticks an element onto a list, and `++` concatenates two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
myLast :: [a] -> a 
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]

myReverse (x:xs) = myLast xs    +     myReverse xs
                   \___a___/          \____[a]___/

          (x:xs)  :: [a]
          ---------------
           x      ::  a
             xs   :: [a]                        xs :: [a]               
      myLast      :: [a] -> a         myReverse    :: [a] -> [a]
     -------------------------       ----------------------------
      myLast xs   ::        a         myReverse xs ::        [a]

myReverse (x:xs)                                   ::        [a]
```

but

```
> :t (+)
                               (+) :: Num a =>  a  ->  a  ->  a
```

which means that the type of the thing on the left of `+` and the type of the thing on the right must be the same.

But they can't be: as we just saw above, in your code the first (of `myLast xs`) is some type `a`, and the second (of `myReverse xs`) is `[a]` the *list* of those same `a`s.

These two can't be the same, because it would mean

```
              a  ~  [a]             OK, this is given to us, then
                     a  ~ [a]       we can use it, so that
                 --------------
              a  ~ [[a]]            this must hold;
                     a  ~ [a]       we know this, then
                 --------------
             a  ~ [[[a]]]           this must also hold; and
                     a  ~ [a]       ........
                 --------------     ........
             a ~ [[[[a]]]]          ........
          .........................
```

and so on ad infinitum, thus making this `a` an "infinite" type. Hence the error.

You could fix it by replacing the `+` with

```
                              (+++) ::         a  ->  [a]  ->  [a]
```

and implementing it to do what you need it to do.

You will also need to fix your *off-by-one* error whereby you completely ignore the first element in the received input, `x`.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) function adds two numbers (of the same type) together. So for example if `a ~ Int`, it will add two `Int`s together, but not an `Int` and a `[Int]`.

But even if the `(+)` operator for example would prepend an item to a list, it would still not reverse the list correctly: your function has no *base case* what to do for an empty list, and your recursive list does nothing with the first item `x` of the list `(x:xs)`.

A simple way to reverse:

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse [] = []
myReverse (x:xs) = myReverse xs ++ [x]
```

But that is not efficient: appending two items will take linear time in the size of the left list. You can work with an accumulator: a parameter that you each time update when you make a recursive call. This looks like:

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse [] = go []
    where go ys (x:xs) = …
    where go ys [] = …
```

where filling in the `…` parts are left as an exercise.